# use of progress bar in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

i simply want that the progress bar progresses a single step , as the timer ticks up one second, but couldn't do it. please help.

shall i use a variable , i , and increment i by 1, in the tick event of the timer.
and write : progressBar1.Increment(i)  --i tried this and it worked.

but why isn't it working with the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer t = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    }
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
```

as one second passes, the tick event occurs, and the progressBar should increment by 1, but here, its just stuck up only at a single increment, i.e. it progresses only by 1 and stops.

Comment: It's a good idea to first add the Handler and then set enabled=true

Comment: I tried it out and your code is working. What are the min and max values for your progressbar?

Answer (score 2):

[It should work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.increment.aspx). Try enabling the timer after assigning the event handler:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t.Interval = 1000;
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    t.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: sir, can you tell that how does this works, i mean , when is the Tick event fired? when t.Enabled is set to true or else?

Comment: why din't it work when the timer was enabled before the event handler?

Comment: also please tell my about maximun and minimum property in a simple language with example?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably working.  The problem is your maximum value on your progress bar is probably so high that it takes a while for the value of the progress bar to be high enough to display the next block.

Set your maximum to 100 and you should see that your code works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Missing Timer Start, below code suppose to work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer t = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
        // enable timer after the handler attached
        t.Enabled = true;
        // Start the timer.
        t.Start();
    }
    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
```

Comment: -1: [setting Enabled to true and calling Start are equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled.aspx).